# What is the proper way to pull data into a fullcalendar view when the view changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to pull event/resource data from the server when the view changes (user moves to the next day, switches between agendaDay view, month view, etc...)

It seems like I could tie to the viewRender callback for this, but it doesn't feel right.  The docs don't really address the correct way to do this.

Comment: The calendar should automatically send a GET request with the date range it needs events for. See [events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) documentation. `FullCalendar will visit the URL whenever it needs new event data. This happens when the user clicks prev/next or changes views. FullCalendar will determine the date-range it needs events for and will pass that information along in GET parameters.`

Comment: This is what I was looking for on event data.  

There also appears to be `resources` callback for getting resource data as a JSON feed, but the documentation for that has no mention of it happening on next/prev or view change in the same manner as the events JSON feed. 

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/resources_json_feed/

Comment: To test this you can watch network in your browser inspector for the calls happening as you change calendar views.